# How to fix - could not open port '/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART' in Esp32

Tags: esp32, platformio

I am trying to upload my Esp32 project into ESPWROOM32 using Platform.io.

I tried uploading a simple code using Arduino and its uploading successfully which means the issue is not the cable or the board.

But the moment i switch to Platform.io and try to upload, it gives this issue.

```
Uploading .pio\build\esp32doit-devkit-v1\firmware.bin
esptool.py v3.0
Serial port /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bbbb\.platformio\packages\tool-esptoolpy\esptool.py", line 3969, in <module>
    _main()
  File "C:\Users\bbbb\.platformio\packages\tool-esptoolpy\esptool.py", line 3962, in _main
    main()
  File "C:\Users\bbbb\.platformio\packages\tool-esptoolpy\esptool.py", line 3551, in main
    esp = chip_class(each_port, initial_baud, args.trace)
  File "C:\Users\bbbb\.platformio\packages\tool-esptoolpy\esptool.py", line 271, in __init__
    self._port = serial.serial_for_url(port)
  File "c:\users\bbbb\.platformio\penv\lib\site-packages\serial\__init__.py", line 90, in serial_for_url
    instance.open()
  File "c:\users\bbbb\.platformio\penv\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 64, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port '/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the path specified.', None, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `platformio.ini` file, set the **upload_port** and **monitor_port** to the COM port to which your ESP32 is connected. e.g.,

```
[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
framework = arduino
upload_port = COM5
monitor_port = COM5
monitor_speed = 115200
```